# Use input from a file for a command

Tags: bash, command-line

I want to use the mac address stored in a file in aireplay-ng command. I want this command to be executed once with each mac address in the file. Can you please tell me how to do it?

```
sudo aireplay-ng -1 0 -e VMC_AP -a  D4:4C:24:2B:EE:80 -h CC:AF:78:B3:E5:0F mon0 --ignore-negative-one
```

I want `-h  CC:AF:78:B3:E5:0F` to be replaced by different mac address stored in a file .

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pure shell

```
while read line
do
  sudo aireplay-ng -1 0 -e VMC_AP -a  D4:4C:24:2B:EE:80 -h "${line}" mon0 --ignore-negative-one 
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command:

```
user@host:~# cat file | awk '{printf "sudo aireplay-ng -1 0 -e VMC_AP -a  D4:4C:24:2B:EE:80 -h %s mon0 --ignore-negative-one\n", $1}' | bash
```

Where `file` looks like this:

```
user@host:~# cat file
AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
```